Failed to send nameservice request for __MSBROWSE__
jcifs.netbios.NameServiceClientImpl : Failed to send nameservice request for __MSBROWSE__
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.sendFromNativeBuffer(DatagramChannelImpl.java:901)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(DatagramChannelImpl.java:863)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(DatagramChannelImpl.java:821)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.blockingSend(DatagramChannelImpl.java:853)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.send(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:218)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:664)
    at jcifs.netbios.NameServiceClientImpl.send(NameServiceClientImpl.java:442)
    at jcifs.netbios.NameServiceClientImpl.getByName(NameServiceClientImpl.java:605)
    at jcifs.netbios.NameServiceClientImpl.doNameQuery(NameServiceClientImpl.java:212)
    at jcifs.netbios.NameServiceClientImpl.getNbtByName(NameServiceClientImpl.java:708)
    at jcifs.netbios.NameServiceClientImpl.getNbtByName(NameServiceClientImpl.java:695)
    at jcifs.netbios.NameServiceClientImpl.getNbtByName(NameServiceClientImpl.java:55)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbResourceLocatorImpl.getFirstAddress(SmbResourceLocatorImpl.java:545)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbResourceLocatorImpl.getAddress(SmbResourceLocatorImpl.java:484)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbEnumerationUtil.doEnum(SmbEnumerationUtil.java:191)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbEnumerationUtil.list(SmbEnumerationUtil.java:243)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.list(SmbFile.java:1176)
    at org.springframework.integration.smb.session.SmbSession.listNames(SmbSession.java:169)
    at com.krungsri.uchoose.uassist.service.smb.SmbServiceImpl.listName(SmbServiceImpl.kt:43)

override fun session(): SmbSession {
    log.info("${smbConfig.username}  : ${smbConfig.password}")
    val smbSession = SmbSessionFactory()
    smbSession.host = smbConfig.host
    smbSession.port = smbConfig.port.toInt()
    smbSession.username = smbConfig.username
    smbSession.password = smbConfig.password
    smbSession.shareAndDir = smbConfig.rootDir

    log.info("connect: ${smbSession.username}:${smbSession.password}@${smbSession.host}${smbSession.shareAndDir}:${smbSession.port} - ${smbSession.domain}")
    return smbSession.session
}

    override fun listName(session: SmbSession, path: String): List<String> {
        return session.listNames(path).map { it }
    }

I successfully connected to smb but I'm trying to use Smbsession.listName encountered a problem.
I've done it on my own Local with no problems. But when I try to connect to the server, I encounter a problem.
Or that my server session doesn't have a username, password, or domain specified? I'm not sure if it's the same or not.
